# Can access mySQL only with --skip-grant-tables argument (all other threads checked)

Tags: mysql, sql, directadmin

So while started with --skip-grant-tables I tried the following:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

This gives:

`ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

Then tried to bypass that I found a threat that told me to do: 
`CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';`
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

That worked, so then I tried to change the password for root, restarted mysqld without --skip-grant-tables and tried to login ... Access denied with the password I had just set.

Then I tried to recreate the whole root user so first I repeated the above steps to bypass the limitations of --skip-grant-tables, deleted the root user and then did:

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user 
SET user = 'root', 
    host = 'localhost', 
    authentication_string = 'nDSExgwoz4ZknHdeSgBPq8Pw2L',
    Select_priv = 'y',
    Insert_priv = 'y',
    Update_priv = 'y',
    Delete_priv = 'y',
    Create_priv = 'y',
    Drop_priv = 'y',
    Reload_priv = 'y',
    Shutdown_priv = 'y',
    Process_priv = 'y',
    File_priv = 'y',
    Grant_priv = 'y',
    References_priv = 'y',
    Index_priv = 'y',
    Alter_priv = 'y',
    Show_db_priv = 'y',
    Super_priv = 'y',
    Create_tmp_table_priv = 'y',
    Lock_tables_priv = 'y',
    Execute_priv = 'y',
    Repl_slave_priv = 'y',
    Repl_client_priv = 'y',
    Create_view_priv = 'y',
    Show_view_priv = 'y',
    Create_routine_priv = 'y',
    Alter_routine_priv = 'y',
    Create_user_priv = 'y',
    Event_priv = 'y',
    Trigger_priv = 'y',
    ssl_cipher = 'y',
    x509_issuer = 'y',
    Create_tablespace_priv = 'y',
    x509_subject = 'y';
```

Restarted mysqld again without --skip-grant-tables.. still access denied.. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Using mysql 8.0.17

Comment: What authentication plugin is used?

Comment: Im not sure, what exactly you mean with authentication plugin, so I will list what the setup is composed of:

CentOs
DirectAdmin
phpMyadmin
Mysql8

Comment: MySQL included great documentation which, amongst other things, [includes instruction how to reset root passwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html). As a plus, its even correct for the 8.0 version unlike the other 1/2 answers around the internet that you have used.

Comment: I have the same issue. The ONLY way to login to mysq 8.0.19 is by using the skip-grant-tables. Any attempt to modify the password  results in the error - "The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and completely reinstalled mysql. The misconfiguration was inside the sys and sql databases..